# Windows Vista Business does not respond on browse

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, not-responding

I have Windows Vista Business(64-Bit) as operating system and when I try to browse something in some folders vista falls into the "Not responding" case sometimes. Does anybody encounter a problem like that or have an idea to solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen in the Windows 7 RC too, and it was relate to my ISO mounting software (SlySoft Virtual Clone Drive, but could have been and ISO mounting software), you may want to check if that is causing an issue and update to the latest version.

Comment: Very interesting, I had Virtual CloneDrive on my Windows 7 Beta machine as well.  Haven't had the issue on the RC yet, but we'll see...

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

I experience the same on a Lenovo R61 laptop with Windows Vista Business. I haven't solved the problem yet, neither do I know the cause.

I was suspecting that it might be a problem with my hardware but that was just wildly guessing. It would be greate if anyone had some tips on how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I either didn't find the cause it then I sold the computer :) But As you told I think it was because of the hardware I. Mine was acer aspire 5930.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that happen in Windows 7 Beta (not RC).  Not sure if I had it happen in Vista, but I'm wondering if the indexing service could be causing the hang up.  You might want to try turning it off and seeing how responsive the system is for you.